# atmosphere, jboss and primefaces push. Get them to work

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces, jboss7.x, atmosphere

I'm trying to get it to work primefaces, jboss eap 6.2 and primefaces push, that is based on atmosphere. I'm fighting with it for quite some time and I'm getting nowhere, so here I am. 
So here some info on my configuration. Inside my standalone.xml i've set to true the usenative flag, and this is my web.xml:
    
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
        sra-EE

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.primefaces.extensions.DELIVER_UNCOMPRESSED_RESOURCES</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

and inside the pom.xml I have:

```
 <dependency>  
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>  
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>  
    <version>2.1.1</version>  
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

on deploy I get this error:

```
12:05:48,544 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
12:05:48,545 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) AnnotationProcessor class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$ServletContainerInitializerAnnotationProcessor being used
12:05:48,546 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Unable to detect annotations. Application may fail to deploy.
12:05:48,547 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Auto detecting atmosphere handlers /WEB-INF/classes/
12:05:48,554 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
12:05:48,558 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
12:05:48,560 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Found multiple containers, please specify which one to use: org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport, org.atmosphere.container.TomcatCometSupport,  until you do, Atmosphere will use:class org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport
12:05:48,562 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptor
12:05:48,563 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
12:05:48,563 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
12:05:48,565 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
12:05:48,566 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
12:05:48,566 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor : Heartbeat Interceptor Support
12:05:48,567 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
12:05:48,567 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
12:05:48,568 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
12:05:48,568 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
12:05:48,568 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
12:05:48,569 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
12:05:48,569 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
12:05:48,573 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper
12:05:48,573 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
12:05:48,574 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
12:05:48,574 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
12:05:48,574 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Shared ExecutorService supported: true
12:05:48,603 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Messaging Thread Pool Size: Unlimited
12:05:48,604 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
12:05:48,604 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
12:05:48,605 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
12:05:48,605 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) HttpSession supported: false
12:05:48,605 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
12:05:48,605 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport running under container: JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1
12:05:48,606 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Atmosphere Framework 2.1.1 started.
12:05:48,606 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) 

    For Atmosphere Framework Commercial Support, visit 
    http://www.async-io.org/ or send an email to support@async-io.org

12:05:48,607 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere LifeCycle with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
12:05:48,608 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
12:05:48,609 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor UUID Tracking Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
12:05:48,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "SRA-ear-1.0.ear" with deployment "SRA-ear-1.0.ear"
12:05:48,813 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (Thread-101) Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.1.5
12:06:56,257 ERROR [org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport] (http-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080-1) HttpEvent is null, JBoss APR Not Properly installed
12:06:56,257 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080-1) Failed using comet support: org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport, error: JBoss failed to detect this is a Comet application because the APR Connector is not enabled. 
Make sure atmosphere-compat-jboss.jar is not under your WEB-INF/lib and You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
there is no context.xml under WEB-INF Is the NIO or APR Connector enabled?
12:06:56,257 ERROR [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080-1) If you have more than one Connector enabled, make sure they both use the same protocol, e.g NIO/APR or HTTP for all. If not, org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport will be used and cannot be changed.: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBoss failed to detect this is a Comet application because the APR Connector is not enabled. 
Make sure atmosphere-compat-jboss.jar is not under your WEB-INF/lib and You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
there is no context.xml under WEB-INF
    at org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport.<clinit>(JBossWebCometSupport.java:49) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:225) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveMultipleNativeSupportConflict(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:316) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveNativeCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:300) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:279) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:1579) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:717) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:614) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:91) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:80) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.primefaces.push.PushServlet.init(PushServlet.java:43) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

12:06:56,260 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080-1) Using org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport
```

I understand that this is not the right way of doing it but... it works, somehow. The problem is if more than one user is using my application atmosphere doesn't seems to understand to who send what, and mess things up.

So I've changed my pom to the following:

```
<dependency>  
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>  
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime-native</artifactId>  
        <version>2.1.1</version>  
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-websockets</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency
```

no error on deploy but it doesn't not work. It sends messages but it makes a mess, even with one user. Deploy info:

```
12:25:34,391 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
12:25:34,392 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) AnnotationProcessor class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$BytecodeBasedAnnotationProcessor being used
12:25:34,870 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Auto detecting atmosphere handlers /WEB-INF/classes/
12:25:34,879 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
12:25:34,883 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
12:25:34,895 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptor
12:25:34,895 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
12:25:34,895 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
12:25:34,896 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
12:25:34,897 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
12:25:34,897 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor : Heartbeat Interceptor Support
12:25:34,898 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
12:25:34,898 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
12:25:34,899 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
12:25:34,899 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
12:25:34,899 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
12:25:34,900 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
12:25:34,900 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
12:25:34,903 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper
12:25:34,904 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
12:25:34,904 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
12:25:34,904 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
12:25:34,904 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Shared ExecutorService supported: true
12:25:34,933 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Messaging Thread Pool Size: Unlimited
12:25:34,933 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
12:25:34,933 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
12:25:34,933 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
12:25:34,933 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) HttpSession supported: false
12:25:34,933 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
12:25:34,933 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebSocketSupport running under container: JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1
12:25:34,935 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Atmosphere Framework 2.1.1 started.
12:25:34,935 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) 

    For Atmosphere Framework Commercial Support, visit 
    http://www.async-io.org/ or send an email to support@async-io.org

12:25:34,935 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) AtmosphereServlet with native support for Tomcat 6/7 and JBossWeb Installed.
12:25:34,936 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere LifeCycle with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
12:25:34,937 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
12:25:34,938 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor UUID Tracking Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
12:25:35,057 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "SRA-ear-1.0.ear" with deployment "SRA-ear-1.0.ear"
12:25:35,144 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (Thread-77) Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.1.5
```

also, it mess with something once called and my application crashes with the following stack trace:

```
12:30:50,264 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host]] (http-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080-3) JBWEB000238: Exception sending request destroyed lifecycle event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getExceptionHandler(FacesContext.java:284) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEventContext.getListenersForEventClass(ExceptionQueuedEventContext.java:262) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2102) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:289) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:293) [jboss-as-weld-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener.requestDestroyed(WebappLifecycleListener.java:123) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.requestDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:348) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
```

and this one after a while:

```
12:33:20,952 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SRA-web].[FacesServlet]] (http-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080-2) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000028: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:609) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:191) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:778) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:433) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:72) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:577) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:115) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:134) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
```

changing the dependency from atmosphere-runtime-native to atmosphere-runtime doesn't change the situazion.
Sorry for filling this page with stack traces :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe (per the docs) that PrimeFaces Push allows you to push messages to all connected clients. At least, it doesn't show in the docs how to direct push messages to specific clients. This can be done with websockets though - you need to track the connected sessions and send messages to just the session for the client that you need to send a message to. See the Websockets section in the EE7 Tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/websocket005.htm#BABFCGBJ